# Custom __del__ not existing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following class:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, type='new'):
        self.type=type
    def __del__(self):
        print ('Deleted')
        super().__del__()

>>> i=Item()
>>> del i
```

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**del**'

How would I properly delete this object, if I'm in a custom delete method?

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) says that there exists a `__new__`, `__init__`, and `__del__` for every object, but I'm only seeing two when testing in python 3.6:

```
>>> object.__new__
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x100922700>
>>> object.__init__
<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>
>>> object.__del__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__del__'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just omit the call to super.

Comment: `super` requires you inherit from something, as it points to the parent class. Here there is no parent that you are inheriting from, so, AttributeError

Comment: @MadPhysicist how does it automatically delete the obect then?

Comment: @C.Nivs that's not 100% accurate, all classes inherit from `object` (in py3, which is tagged here)

Comment: David542: Python reference-counts objects and reclaims them automatically, so you generally don't need to worry about doing it yourself. Anyway, were in the documentation does it say every object a `__del__()` method?

Comment: @martineau I think user2357112 explains it a bit where it says it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the data model docs say `object.__whatever__`, they don't mean that the `object` class has a `__whatever__` method. They mean that if an object has a `__whatever__` method, it should behave as the following documentation describes, and it will be implicitly invoked for the reasons the documentation describes.

`object` itself doesn't have most of those methods. For methods like `__del__`, if your superclass doesn't have the method, just don't make a `super()` call.

Also, `__del__` isn't a `del` hook or a destructor - it's a finalizer, called before an object would be reclaimed by the memory management system. Using `del` doesn't mean an object's `__del__` will necessarily be invoked, and `__del__` isn't responsible for freeing memory, so you don't need to call some superclass `__del__` that knows how to free the object.

Comment: I see -- thanks for the explanation. Yea, it seems a bit useless. Half the times I would delete an object it wouldn't actually run the `__del__` until after the program finished executing (even though there were zero other references to that object).

Comment: @David542: There were probably references you hadn't yet learned to look for, perhaps something like the `_` variable that holds the last expression statement result in interactive mode. While Python implementations aren't required to run `__del__` promptly, CPython usually does.

Comment: @David542: I've been programming Python a long time, and I can't remember the last time I need to implement the method — and, in fact, if you read the documentation very closely, you'll note that there's no guarantee if will _ever_ get called. Python isn't like C++ in this respect.

Comment: If `__del__` isn't guaranteed to run, what is the purpose?

Comment: David542: It's for releasing external resources an object may be using (not for freeing the memory the occupied by the object). Since it might not be called, you can make sure by calling it explicitly (i.e. via `obj.__del__()`, _not_ `del obj`) if that's necessary for some reason — like, say, to release some limited external resource. Be careful though, because doing so won't delete the object, so you would likely needed to also make sure there will be no other reference attempts made to whatever was released. I think that's what the **Warning** is about in the `object.__del__()` documentation

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR don't call `super().__del__()`, your instance will delete just fine. Overriding `__del__` is provided to perform cleanup.

`Item` inherits from `object`. If you open a Python3 console

```
>>> dir(object())
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

`__del__` is not defined.